# Slider positioning width

Tags: jquery, css

I have a slider I made: http://dranz1r.com/index.html

When you slide right for example, there is a space between the image to the right edge.
I can't understand how this space is created since everything's width is 1100px.

Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image wasn't wide enought to fill the slider

```
     .slider {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 1090px;   //this line
height: 300px;
margin: 60px auto;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Make the container 10 px smaller, or 20 px smaller, not the image larger, if the image is too large it overflows into the next slide